# Embed page in angular material sidenav structure

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to add pages dynamically into the angular material sidenav structure. My sidenav code is as follows

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle()"></button>
</mat-toolbar>

<div fxLayout="row">
    <mat-drawer-container>
        <mat-drawer #snav [mode]="'side'">
            <mat-nav-list>
                <a mat-list-item>Home</a>
            </mat-nav-list>
        </mat-drawer>
        <mat-drawer-content>
            <p>content</p>
        </mat-drawer-content>
    </mat-drawer-container>
</div>
```

Now on my home page I am calling the sidenav selector

```
<app-sidenav></app-sidenav>    
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

My question is how do I add the home page html into the sidenav content area?

Comment: What does this mean `home page html into the sidenav content area` ? Do you want to pass a list of links or do you want to pass html? And if you do pass html where in the page should it appear?

Comment: I want to pass the entire home.html in to the sidenav content area `<mat-drawer-content>`